# Katalon TFS CI Pipeline/Release Management

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, katalon-studio

I am sorry, I do not have any code or implementation to show.  I just need to know if anyone has documentation on integrating katalon studio tests into the CI/CD or release management pipeline using TFS.

Answer (score -1):

### Taken from the Katalon [docs](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/vststfsvso-integration.html):

Below is a general guide on how to configure Katalon Studio on VSO (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/) with the assumptions that you are already familiar with common VSO terms such as agent, build, task……

**1. Setting up agent:**

Follow setup guide: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows to set up and run a local agent.

Make sure the agent is in ‘Online’ status.

**2. Setting up build steps:**

Add a new build task: “Command Line”:

- Tool: katalon.exe
- Arguments: Generate command line from Katalon Studio (WITHOUT katalon prefix) to be used in console mode (https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Console+Mode+Execution)
- projectPath value uses VSO build variable to get project location, e.g: `-runMode=console -projectPath=”$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Sample Web Testing Project.prj” -reportFolder=”Reports” -reportFileName=”report” -retry=0 -testSuitePath=”Test Suites/TS_RegressionTest” -browserType=”Chrome” -noSplash`
- Advanced:
  Working folder: Select Katalon Studio folder, e.g: C:\4.6\Katalon Studio Windows 64

**3. Building your project with the agent:**

Configure your project to be built with the agent. In this example, the agent is in ‘Default’ queue group, so we will choose ‘Default’ queue when selecting new build.